# model is not creating undet the custom schema in DBT

Tags: dbt

Here is my code

```yaml
models:
  dbt-cts-training:
    tranform:
      +schema: transforming
```

when I try to crate models under transforming schema but when I ran the model it is creating under the default schema

I can't seem to find the error.

when I try the config() in the model itself the model is creating under the custom schema

I want to crate model under custom schema by using the dbt_project.yml file

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is that you have used `tranform` in your YML and your directory may be called `transform` with an 's', causing the config to miss your model.